# System.ArgumentException: 'Keyword not supported: 'metadata

Tags: c#, entity-framework

What is this Error.

> System.ArgumentException: 'Keyword not supported: 'metadata'.'

Line of follow is my app.config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="Foroush.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
    </startup>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ForoushEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataModel.csdl|res://*/DataModel.ssdl|res://*/DataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=Foroush;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <applicationSettings>
        <Foroush.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="Foroush_SmsWebService_SendReceive" serializeAs="String">
                <value>http://ip.sms.ir/ws/SendReceive.asmx</value>
            </setting>
        </Foroush.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

[For Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNHhh.png)

Comment: That connection string has issues.

Comment: Please add the error message and the code generating it as text to the question, not as an image as it is vital to understand your issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the screenshot I see you alter the connection string by replacing an important part with `""` in an attempt to create a Sql Connection String instead of an Entity Framework Connection String.

There are build-in methods for that like:

```
var entityConnectionStringBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(MyConnectionString);

string sqlConnectionString = entityConnectionStringBuilder.ProviderConnectionString;

return new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder(sqlConnectionString).UserId);
```

In the screenshot code you probably wanted to use `ConnectionStringNewFormat` as an argument in the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` instead of `MyConnectionString` (which is the original Entity Framework Connection String. But please, do not use string manipulation but use the code provided to you by the Entity Framework as demonstrated above.